# Parsing different pages with urlparse

Tags: python, scrapy, urlparse, scrapy-shell

I am trying to parse multiple pages of a website but I can't understand how to change the query of the url (if this makes sense?)

I tried to create a next_page that took the first page and added +1 everytime it found the next page element, but I think I can't because I'll have multiple start urls (all similar). When i try to get the information of the next page element it returns this:

> ["loadmoreresult('?networkId=24&pageNumber=2&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=1&networkIds=2&networkIds=3&networkIds=4&networkIds=61&networkIds=98&networkIds=108&networkIds=6&networkIds=5&networkIds=22&networkIds=13&networkIds=18&networkIds=15&networkIds=16&networkIds=105&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&city=&keyword=&lastCid=116490'); return false;"]

Using url.parse(response.url).query I get:

> 'networkId=24&pageNumber=1&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=1&networkIds=2&networkIds=3&networkIds=4&networkIds=61&networkIds=98&networkIds=108&networkIds=6&networkIds=5&networkIds=22&networkIds=13&networkIds=18&networkIds=15&networkIds=16&networkIds=105&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&city=&keyword='

All I need to do is create a new link that uses the same scheme, path and then changes the query.

If you need more info please tell me, I don't really know what is more relevant to you as I am still a beginner.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin

urlparse(response.url)
>>> ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.wcaworld.com', path='/Directory', params='', query='networkId=24&pageNumber=1&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=1&networkIds=2&networkIds=3&networkIds=4&networkIds=61&networkIds=98&networkIds=108&networkIds=6&networkIds=5&networkIds=22&networkIds=13&networkIds=18&networkIds=15&networkIds=16&networkIds=105&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&city=&keyword=', fragment='')

response.css('a.loadmore::attr(onmouseover)').extract()
>>>["loadmoreresult('?networkId=24&pageNumber=2&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=1&networkIds=2&networkIds=3&networkIds=4&networkIds=61&networkIds=98&networkIds=108&networkIds=6&networkIds=5&networkIds=22&networkIds=13&networkIds=18&networkIds=15&networkIds=16&networkIds=105&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&city=&keyword=&lastCid=116490'); return false;"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the base url of that `<a>` element, which is the part of a url before query string starts `https://example.com/a/path/?query=param` so here the base url would be `https://example.com/a/path/`. Save that into a variable. Then use `urllib.parse.parse_qsl` to parse the query string, then update the page number and join it with base url.

```py
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urljoin, urlencode

BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/a/path/'
# you can also extract base url from scrapy.Response object
# BASE_URL, _ = splitquery(response.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # extract query parameter from from a url
    q = 'networkId=24&pageNumber=2&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=1&networkIds=2&networkIds=3&networkIds=4&networkIds=61&networkIds=98&networkIds=108&networkIds=6&networkIds=5&networkIds=22&networkIds=13&networkIds=18&networkIds=15&networkIds=16&networkIds=105&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&city=&keyword=&lastCid=116490'
    parsed = dict(parse_qsl(q))
    next_page = int(parsed['pageNumber']) + 1
    parsed['pageNumber'] = next_page

    next_page_url = urljoin(BASE_URL, '?' + urlencode(parsed))

    print(next_page_url)
```

output:

```
https://example.com/a/path/networkId=24&pageNumber=3&pageSize=100&allnet=yes&networkIds=38&licenseIds=0&searchby=CountryCode&orderby=CountryCity&country=ES&lastCid=116490
```

Comment: Sorry but how canI get the href value? In my case, the site has href="#" so all I have is really the query. Also, for the Base url, should I do something like scheme + '://' + netloc + path? thank you.

Comment: You already have it: `urlparse(response.url).query`, gives you the query parameter.

Comment: thank you, but isn't the 'lastCid' argument needed? It is still not working, I'm going to sleep to hopefully understand it better tomorrow!

Comment: you are correct. It still doesn't work because I was not able to correctly define the rules for the crawlspider. But thank you for the help!